# (+/-)Infinity in JSON Imports

Tags: json, google-bigquery, infinity

With BigQuery and the Python API, I am trying to pass infinity to a FLOAT column in a JSON column.  Given the `IS_INF()` function, it seems it's supported, but I can't find any documentation on how to specify this in the JSON file.

Any advice/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: To my knowledge, JSON does not have representations for infinity or NaN.

Comment: (BTW, it would be useful to specify what language you're using, and what JSON kit.)

Comment: What `IS_INF()` function? This looks like a language-specific construct. JSON is language-agnostic.

Comment: This is not a question. I recommend you take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting again.

Comment: Updated comment and tagging for google-bigquery.  It is specific to that platform; apologies for the mis-tag.

Answer (score -2):

JSON doesn't allow you to use either infinity or not-a-number. No way. Even if you could, no JSON parser would accept the result.